# Python 3 requests кодировка

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Получаю страничку, она в ISO-8859-1

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.fonbet.com/live/?locale=ru'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)
# print(r.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

В print() вижу:

```
<!-- ÐÐÐ Ð¡ÐÐ¯: 94 -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ÐÐµÑÐºÐ°Ð»Ð¾ Ð¤Ð¾Ð½Ð±ÐµÑ â www.fonbet52.com â Ð»Ð¸Ð±Ð¾ +1 Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ +2 - Ð´Ð¾ÑÑÑÐ¿ Ðº ÑÐ°Ð¹ÑÑ Ð±ÑÐºÐ¼ÐµÐºÐµÑÐ° </title>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как декодировать в читаемый текст?

Comment: Технически это дубликат вопроса: [Русские символы из ответа requests выводятся в виде каракуль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/940280/1365)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если сайт в http заголовке отдает неправильную кодировку, решить можно так:

```
r = requests.get(url)
r.encoding = 'utf-8'  # указываем правильную кодировку принудительно
print(r.text)
```

Либо, можно обратиться к полю `r.content`, там ответ хранится в виде байт, которые можно декодировать с указанием правильной кодировки:

```
print(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Порешалось первым вариантом, спасибо за ответ. Часа 3 искал это решение.