# Русские символы из ответа requests выводятся в виде каракуль

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

В общем, есть текстовый документ, в нём располагается русский текст, но при выводе получаются каракули

Не важно, вывод идёт в консоль или куда-то еще, всё равно получаются каракули, как из этого сделать нормальный текст?

OS - windows 10 (UPD Пробовал на Ubuntu, тоже самое)
Python - 3.6.3

Консоль
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример кода:

```
import requests
VTCr = requests.get("somesite.com")
VTCdata = VTCr.json()
VTClog = requests.get(VTCdata["Update"]).text
print(VTClog)
```

Что получается на выходе:
ï»¿[add] ÐÐ¾Ð±Ð°Ð²Ð»ÐµÐ½ ÑÐ°Ð·Ð´ÐµÐ» "ÐÐ¾Ñ ÐºÐ¾Ð¼Ð¿Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ";
[fix] ÐÐ¿ÑÐ°Ð²Ð»ÐµÐ½ ÑÐ°ÑÑÐµÑ Ð²ÐµÐ»Ð¸ÑÐ¸Ð½ Ð´Ð»Ñ ATS;

Comment: Выводятся откуда куда? Если «Не важно», всё равно продемонстрируйте хоть какой-нибудь пример. [mcve] в студию

Comment: @andreymal добавил

Comment: Какие-то непонятные картинки не являются примером. Ещё раз: [mcve]

Comment: @andreymal Вроде готово

Comment: попробуйте в винде выполнить команду `chcp 65001`

Comment: @BuzzardDoc в продемонстрированном случае сервер прислал именно эти самые каракули, и поведение Python корректное и не требует никаких исправлений. Обращайтесь к администратору сервера, чтобы он исправил свои тексты или их кодировку

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Прежде всего, смотрим на диаграмму из статьи [Как распознать кракозябры?](https://habr.com/ru/post/147843/):

[image: Диаграмма]

Понимаем, что исходная кодировка UTF-8, ошибочно декодированная как win1252.

Теперь, возвращаемся к вашему коду, а именно к 4 строке. Вместо того, чтобы сразу пытаться получить текст, сначала просто получаем результат запроса

```
response = requests.get(url)
```

Смотрим кодировку ответа:

```
>>> response.encoding
'ISO-8859-1'
```

Что примерно то же самое, что win-1252 (есть разница в некоторых символах, но в данном случае она несущественна).

Отсюда вывод: сервер в ответе указывает неправильную кодировку текста.

Решить проблему без изменения поведения сервера можно несколькими способами

1. Меняем кодировку ответа на правильную, после этого извлекаем текст:

   ```
   >>> response.encoding = 'utf-8'

   >>> response.text
   '\ufeff[add] Добавлен раздел "Моя компания";\n[fix] Исправлен расчет величин для ATS;'
   ```
2. Вместо `text` берем `content` (полученные данные в виде байт) и декодируем из utf-8, получаем тот же результат:

   ```
   >>> response.content.decode('utf-8')
   '\ufeff[add] Добавлен раздел "Моя компания";\n[fix] Исправлен расчет величин для ATS;'
   ```
3. Если работаете с BeautifulSoup, то передавайте в него `response.content` вместо `response.text`, bs сам получит кодировку из мета-тегов и правильно все декодирует.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо задавать кодировку. Желательно использовать UTF-8. При выводе в кодировке UTF-8 у вас файл должен быть так же закодирован в UTF-8. Если работаете с базой данных она так же должна быть в кодировке UTF-8