# Изменить кодировку строки с windows-1252 на windows-1251

Tags: python

У меня есть строка полученная с помощью requests с сайта.

```
r = requests.get("https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=1")
```

После некоторых преобразований с тем, что я получаю, я выбираю оттуда то, что мне нужно.
Это выглядит примерно так: "Òðåáóåòñÿ ñëîæèòü äâà öåëûõ ÷èñëà À è Â. Âõîäíûå äàííûå Â åäèíñòâåííîé ñòðîêå âõîäíîãî ôàéëà" 
Использовав интернет, я узнал что этот текст закодирован с помощью windows-1252, а мне нужна windows-1251. Я немного поигрался с encode и decode, но ничего не вышло. Возможно ли преобразовать эту строку в нормальную кириллицу? Если возможно то как это сделать?

Comment: "После некоторых преобразований с тем, что я получаю" - каких именно преобразований?

Comment: Кодировку нужно указывать в самом реквесте. Свойство encoding.

Comment: 1251 от 1252 отличается положением ё или както так. Тут больше похоже на utf8

Comment: @insolor не суть, я просто достал подстроку из большого ответа, полученного от requests.

Comment: Свойство encoding. [link](https://repl.it/repls/MediumblueMadOutcome)

Comment: @eri, ошибаетесь https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set

Comment: @lesstrq, первый вариант - свойство encoding вашего объекта r. Второй вариант - брать сырое байтовое представление ответа (свойство content того же объекта) и декодировать из кодировки cp1251.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Русские символы выводятся в виде каракуль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/940280/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c)