# Кракозяблы - иероглифы в запросе request через время

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests

Всем привет!
Есть парсер на сайт olimp.bet. Парсинг начинается по ссылке https://www.olimp.bet/apiru/live/matches/all - ответ json, библиотека requests 2.13.0. Через время начинаются проблемы - кракозяблы - иероглифы в ответе. С чем может быть связано? Менял IP и заголовки - не помогает. Через время восстанавливается ответ в норм кодировку.

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот ответ, возможно поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/940350/1365

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос через Selenium. Все работает норм, видимо в заголовках и куки стало не хватать данных. Буду разбираться дальше.