# Как изменить кодировку конечной разметки после parsing-а

Tags: python, парсер

После парсинга разметки на русском языке таким кодом:

```
import requests
import json

school = ''
login = ''
password = ''
data = {'scid': school, 'UN': login, 'PW': password}
r = requests.post("site", data)
with open('result.html', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(r.text)
```

В файле result.html получаю разметку с подобным текстом:

```
<title>Ð­Ð»ÐµÐºÑÑÐ¾Ð½Ð½Ð¾Ðµ Ð¾Ð±ÑÐ°Ð·Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ</title>
```

Дайте совет как это пофиксить

Comment: print(r.encoding) что выводит?

Comment: ISO-8859-1 - это

Comment: попробуйте сменить кодировку r.encoding = 'utf-8'

Comment: непонял где это указывать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python 3 requests кодировка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671608/python-3-requests-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0)