# Не получается определить кодировку ответа сервера

Tags: python, requests, кодировка

Пытаюсь спарсить данный сайт - https://footballprediction365.com/football-predictions/
Но в ответе он отдает что-то непонятное: �^]�9w��h�D���w�{�H3:mp���

Пытался использовать этот код для определения кодировки

```
    import chardet
    import urllib.request

    url = 'https://footballprediction365.com/football-predictions/'

    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    print(chardet.detect(data.read())['encoding'])
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

также использовал этот сайт для декодирования - https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=ru
но все равно не получается узнать правильную кодировку

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python 3 requests кодировка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671608/python-3-requests-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Сайт указывает, в какой кодировке контент, вы тоже можете указывать в запросе, желаемую кодировку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась, когда я удалил headers

```
resp = requests.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Все отлично парситься.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://footballprediction365.com/football-predictions/'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

print(soup.find('p'))
```

ответ

```
<p id="site-description">Football prediction today with 1×2 betting tips, football predictions for BTTS, over/under 2.5 goals and correct score for today’s matches.</p>
```

Comment: У сайта в шапке кодировка UTF-8

Comment: Когда вы отдаёте в `BS` только текст `page.text` вы лишаете его возможность посмотреть хедер сайта, где написана кодировка, отдавайте `page.content` в `BS`.